# Why does style.strokeDashoffset always returns empty, even when set?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

So I'm trying to increment the stroke-dashoffset css of a svg using javascript but I can't get the current stroke-dashoffset of any svg path.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46cmu71t/38/) making it visible in the console this way:

```
setInterval(function(){
    path = document.getElementById("path1");
    console.log(path.style.strokeDashoffset)
},50)
```

How can I get the computed curent stroke-dashoffset value of a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use getComputedStyle() function:

```
setInterval(function(){
  path = document.getElementById("path1");
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(path).strokeDashoffset)
},50)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46cmu71t/39/